# Github for Windows client not resolving conflicts

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

Im on windows 7 and using Github of Windows client
I have 2 branches im am trying to merge with a deliberate conflict so i can see how Github handles them

When i merge the files it says it is done, nothing about finding any conflict, no errors

When i check the merge hasn't been done the 2 branches are still different, no extra data in the files to highlight that github found a problem.

Am i meant to see some kind of warning or be taken to a different screen or something when there is a conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to an error in Github, the work around was to use Powershell and enter the command line equivalent to get the job done